# Fast and Scalable Real-Time Application (Is Hazelcast Jet a good way?)

Tags: hazelcast, vert.x, sockjs, hazelcast-imap, hazelcast-jet

Actually, in our architecture, we use **Hazelcast IMDG**, in order to share information about user operativities among several server nodes.

Our map has the following structure: `[key:String|value: CustomObject]`.

Now, we want to expand our product functionality and we want to develop a real-time dashboard performing real-time data stream by doing:

1. Complex Aggregation
2. Continuous Query
3. etc.

At the end of the process we want to “send” the result to a **Vert.x Eventbus** and then to a socket layer (**SockJS**), in order to show the data in a dashboard.

Our need is to set-up a scalable and fast system, in order to handle a heavy amount of data such as thousands of events per second.

The first image represent our current (old) architecture, the second image represent our “target” architecture.

[Old Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOvkr.png)

[Target Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFGjP.png)

What do you think about *target* architecture?

Is the role of **Hazelcast Jet** correct or are there another way to perform these operations (for example only with **Hazelcast IMDG**)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a good fit for Hazelcast Jet. You probably will use `Sources.mapJournal()` to process entries as they are added to the IMap. You can aggregate into sliding windows easily. Writing a Vert.x Event Bus sink should be straightforward with `SinkBuilder`. Thousands events/s is a low figure, it depends on how much work will you do with each event.